# How do I mathematically model the changes in the shape of a circle projected onto non-flat surfaces at different angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Imagine I shine a flashlight straight down at my feet on a flat surface and it creates a perfect circle of radius 1. If I begin to move my arm forward the light will be projected on the ground at an angle and will draw an ellipse.

I want to know the math that dawns the ellipse at any angle. So at 90 degrees (straight down) its a perfect circle of x^2 + y^2 = 1. What would be the equation of the ellipse if I was shining the flashlight at the ground at 45 degrees? I'm just not sure how to approach this problem, so advice is appreciated. I took linear algebra years ago and I feel like there's some transformation matrix for this somewhere, but my search results havnt given me anything that I found useful yet.

Comment: key words : homography matrix

Comment: The ellipse problem resolves as a scale factor in one direction based on the angle involved (for flat ground), but note that you holding the flashlight have a perspective that also alters the appearance of that ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using analytic geometry. Let us consider that the flashline is at the height of the wrist $W$ situated at a unit height (i.e, for example at 1 meter from the ground). I will take a different convention:

$$\alpha=\text{angle between vertical and axis of the light}$$

Let us denote by $\beta$ the half aperture angle of the cone.

Let us express the equation of the light cone $(C)$ by the constraint:

$$M \in (C) \ \ \iff \ \ \dfrac{\vec{WM}.\vec{u}}{\|\vec{WM}\|\|\vec{u}\|}=\cos\beta$$

which becomes, with $M(x,y,z)$, $W(0,0,1)$, $\vec{u}(\tan \alpha,0,-1)$

$$\dfrac{x\tan \alpha - (z-1)}{\sqrt{1+(\tan \alpha)^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}}=\cos \beta\tag{1}$$

$$\cos \alpha (x\tan \alpha - (z-1))=\cos \beta \sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}\tag{2}$$

$$(x\sin \alpha - \cos \alpha (z-1))=\cos \beta \sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2}\tag{3}$$

Intersection of the light cone with the ground is obtained by setting $z=0$ in (3) giving, squared:

$$(x\sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2=\cos^2 \beta (x^2+y^2+1)\tag{4}$$

We are able, using (4) to plot the corresponding ellipses.

We can also turn (4) into the canonical form:

$$\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

with in particular simple forms for

$$a=\dfrac{1}{2}(\tan(\alpha+\beta)-\tan(\alpha-\beta))$$

$$c=\dfrac{1}{2}(\tan(\alpha+\beta)+\tan(\alpha-\beta))$$

[image]